# How do I span a JLabel accross multiple lines?

Tags: java, jpanel

I don't usually ask questions on here, but I am stumped. I have a JLabel inside of a java application that is rather long in length. Java will not wrap this text onto the next line no matter what I try. I've done research and everyone keeps telling me to put HTML tags around it, but when I try my WHOLE GUI stops working. This is for a school project! All help is very much appreciated!

Below is some of the code: (This is a class file that is being intimated by the main method)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;//needed for button listeners
import java.awt.*;//Layout class

 public class gui extends JFrame implements SwingConstants
{

   //Arrays
   public JPanel[] panels = new JPanel[6];
   public JPanel[] nested_panels = new JPanel[6];
   public JLabel[] productDescriptions = new JLabel[6];
   public product[] home_product_array = new product[6];
   public JLabel[] productTitles = new JLabel[6];
   public JLabel[] productPrices = new JLabel[6];
   public JButton[] buttons = new JButton[6];

  //Constants 
   final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1000;
   final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 800;

  //Main Window
   public JFrame mainWindow;

 /*    
        Constructor
 */
 public gui(){
 //main window
 JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("Clothes 4 Sale");
 //set layout
 mainWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));
 //title of window
 mainWindow.setTitle("Clothes 4 Sale");
 //size of window
 mainWindow.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);
 //Close Button
 mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 //inititate window
 mainWindow.setVisible(true);

//pull first title
productList product_list = new productList();
home_product_array = product_list.get_product_array();



for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
//print whole array
System.out.println(home_product_array[i].get_product_title());
System.out.println(home_product_array[i].get_product_description());
System.out.println(home_product_array[i].get_product_price_string());
//

productTitles[i] = new JLabel(home_product_array[i].get_product_title());
productDescriptions[i] = new 
JLabel(home_product_array[i].get_product_description());
productPrices[i] = new 
JLabel(home_product_array[i].get_product_price_string());
productPrices[i].setForeground(Color.GREEN);
panels[i] = new JPanel();
panels[i].setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,10));
panels[i].add(productTitles[i], BorderLayout.NORTH);
panels[i].add(productDescriptions[i], BorderLayout.CENTER);
nested_panels[i] = new JPanel();
nested_panels[i].add(productPrices[i]);
buttons[i] = new JButton("Add To Cart");
nested_panels[i].add(buttons[i]);
panels[i].add(nested_panels[i], BorderLayout.SOUTH);
mainWindow.add(panels[i]);
}//for loop
/*


*/

  }//End of constructor



  }//end of class file
```

Comment: why not use jtextarea?

Comment: @yelliver that could also fit the bill but with some work too: make it non-editable, set transparent background, remove borders...

Comment: So depending on the need, `JTextArea` might be more suitable. Anyway, what do you mean *exactly* by "the whole GUI stops working"?

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries that support multiline labels, but for a school project you should probably indeed use HTML.

You can use something like this, which will wrap words and respect line breaks (newline characters in original text):

```
/*...*/ new JLabel(asHtml(someMultilineTextString));
/*...*/
private String asHtml(String text) {
    return "<HTML>" + text.replace("\n", "<br>") + "</HTML>";
}
```

Edit: again, this is for a school project. For a real-world program you'd use a library or at the very least escape more than newline character (also with a library).